# Modify Android gradle.properties in Expo Managed App

Tags: android, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I'm working on a Expo React Native project that requires up to 15MB of local storage in android. This requires adding the following to the android/gradle.properties file.

> AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB=10

I've tried creating a plugin with

```
import { withGradleProperties } from "@expo/config-plugins";

export const modifyGradle = (config) => {
      const AsyncKey = "AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB";
      return withGradleProperties(config, (config) => {
        config.modResults.push({
          type: "property",
          key: AsyncKey,
          value: 10,
        });
    
        return config;
      });
    };
```

And then adding to app.json as

```
expo:{
...
"plugins": ["./plugins/modifyGradle.js"],
...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can this be done without ejecting from Expo?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [as stated in docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#what-are-plugins), you should rename your plugin to something like `withModifyGradle` and as far as I can understand, you should not use import, use require instead:

```
const { withGradleProperties } = require('@expo/config-plugins');

module.exports = (config) => {
  const newGraddleProperties = [
    {
      type: 'property',
      key: 'AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB',
      value: '10', // Maybe you should set this to 15?
    },
    // Added this to demostrate multiple gradle properties change
    {
      type: 'property',
      key: 'FLIPPER_VERSION',
     value: '0.144.0', // Fix app names with accented and diacritics characters
    },
  ];

  return withGradleProperties(config, (config) => {
    newGraddleProperties.map((gradleProperty) => config.modResults.push(gradleProperty));

    return config;
  });
};
```

After you create the config plugin set it up in **app.config.js** ([as stated here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#quick-facts)) like this

```
expo:{
    ...
    plugins: [
        ['./plugins/withModifyGradle.js'],
    ],
    ...
}
```

[As stated here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#debugging), you can check if the plugin is working by running `EXPO_DEBUG=1 expo prebuild` in the project directory. After that, you should have an **android** folder with a **gradle.properties** file with the new properties at the end of the file.

If that succeeded, then you are ready to go with **eas build**, but after running that command, I needed to remove **index.js, metro.config.js, android, ios and node_modules** folders, and revert changes to my **package.json** file, then ran **npm install** to get back to expo.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions of expo, the built-in android mod can be used: https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/plugins-and-mods/.

From the docs:

`mods.android.gradleProperties` -> `Modify the android/gradle.properties as a Properties.PropertiesItem[].`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is yout config plugin name, it should be "withModifyGradle.js"

```
Plugins should be named using the following convention: with<Plugin Functionality> i.e. withFacebook.
```

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#creating-a-plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).